# Basic notions on contraction mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

I have a function $H_n: [0,1]^n\rightarrow [0,1]^n$ where $n$ is a positive integer $>1$.

I have to show that $H_n$ is a contraction mapping "uniformly in $n$".

**Question 1**: what does it mean "uniformly in $n$"? Is it correct that it means I have to prove that $\forall \theta_n, \tilde{\theta}_n$
$$
d(H_n(\theta_n),H_n(\tilde{\theta_n})) \leq k d(\theta_n, \tilde{\theta}_n)
$$
with $0\leq k <1$, where $k$ is **invariant over $n$**?

**Question 2**: an hint of the exercise is showing that
$$
(\star)\hspace{1cm}||\frac{\partial H_n(\theta_n)}{\partial \theta'_n}||_{\infty}\leq 1
$$
uniformly in $n$. Firstly, what does it mean that the inequality $(\star)$ should be satisfied "uniformly in $n$"? Secondly, why does it imply that $H_n$ is a contraction mapping "uniformly in $n$"? Which theorem are we using? Does using $\leq$ versus $<$ in $(\star)$ change something?

Comment: Do you have more conditions on $H_n$? Because if you take the identity, it will certainly not be a contraction... (Else, you can consider the product of open intervals, than it will work.) Other than that, the answer to question 1 should be yes.

Comment: Yes, of course, I have a specific $H_n$ to consider. My questions posted here are just about the general interpretation of the exercise.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Could you give me some help with question 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question $1$, you've said nothing about a sequence of functions, which suggests that the standard interpretation of "uniform contraction applies.

In other words, $\|x-y\| \geq c \|f(x)-f(y)\|$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]^n$.

For the hint: use the bounded derivative to show that your function is [locally lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396280/differentiability-implies-lipschitz-continuity), with constant less than $1$ by the hint. Furthermore, since the set is compact, deduce that the function is [globally lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154721/if-locally-lipschitz-implies-lipschitz-on-compacts), with constant less than $1$, since you can choose a finite subcover, and hence choose a maximal constant $K < 1$ to bound your function.

More formally, show that in some $\delta$-neighborhood of $x$, we have $\|x-y\| \geq K_{\delta}\|f(x)-f(y)\|$ with $K_{\delta} <1$ because of the condition on the derivative (Think about the one dimensional case to motivate the argument) and then use these suitable neighborhoods to cover $[0,1]^n$, and use compactness.

Comment: Please check all your inequalities :P

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit  I have no excuse for myself hahaha

Comment: Thank you: does it matter whether I show $<1$ versus $\leq 1$ in $(\star)$? My intuition is that the inequality should be STRICT to have $c<1$ in the contract definition, correct?

Comment: @AndresMejia I am glad, I am not the only one who is making mistakes :D

Comment: It matters a lot. I should be less sloppy.

Comment: @STF Yes, I agree (but this might depend on the definition of _contraction_). If you want to proofe that $H_n$ has fixed points, you might want to use Browders fixed point theorem since $[0,1]^n$ is compact and $H_n$ (lipschitz) continuous.

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit is it correct to say that in order to apply B. fixed point theorem I would need to show that $\forall \theta_n, \tilde{\theta}_n$
$$
d(H_n(\theta_n),H_n(\tilde{\theta_n})) \leq k d(\theta_n, \tilde{\theta}_n)
$$
with $k=1$?

Comment: on the other hand, B. fixed point theorem does not allow to show that the fixed point is unique (as instead the contraction mapping theorem tells)

Comment: Ah, OK, thank you. you meant BROWER and not BROWDER.. these are two different fixed point theorems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browder_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: Oh I am sorry, atm I am working with a Browder theorem :D Yes, $k=1$ is enough and guarantess the continuity of your map. Sorry for confusing you!